# How do I get current keyboard layout?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xkb

I'm wondering if there is any command line tool that returns the current keyboard layout.

I have `XkbLayout` set to `us, ru`.

**Update:** `setxkbmap` returns layout settings, not selected layout. E.g.:

```
$ setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols
xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(grouplock)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"   };
```

It will return the same result no matter what the current layout is.

Comment: I am not really good at D-Bus, but it should be easy to track the current keyboard layout using it I think. Although it may not be able to do so if there is no active switch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current keyboard layout from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402719/how-to-get-current-keyboard-layout-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 46):

Maybe this is version dependent, but on my machine that uses `setxkbmap` 1.3.0 the following command works:

```
setxkbmap -query | grep layout
```

Note that depending on your need it may be useless to know only the layout : for instance the Dvorak variant of the US layout is quite different than the default QWERTY.  The `-query` option of `setxkbmap` gives both the layout and the variant, as different fields :

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      default
layout:     fr
variant:    bepo
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Comment: `-query` was added in [setxkbmap 1.2.0](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2010-September/051048.html)

Comment: You get the current layouts and variants and many additional info with `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`

Comment: To set it, for example both layouts cz and us, the latter with variant dvorak (for a 104 key keyboard), use `setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout cz,us -variant ,dvorak`

Comment: doesn't let you know the active one for multiple layouts, which is what the OP asked. Bummer this got to the top.

Answer (score 26):

Yes THERE IS a command line tool that does what you want!
I just discovered it 10min ago :)

Look at here: https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state

```
xkblayout-state print "%s"
```

does exactly what you want (it doesn't output an end of line, so add `; echo` if you need).
run the tool without parameters for the help.

Answer (score 24):

There is xkb-switch which is described thus:

> xkb-switch is a C++ program that
>   allows to query and change the XKB
>   layout state.

https://github.com/ierton/xkb-switch

Or, following nozimica's suggestion, you could use:

```
setxkbmap -print | awk -F"+" '/xkb_symbols/ {print $2}'
```

From this thread on the Arch Linux boards: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=539406

Comment: Thanks, `xkb-switch` works fine, but I hope that there was more portable solution

Comment: @Andrew: yes it's kind of odd there is no simple way to get the current layout.

Comment: Your `setxkbmap` doesn't show the currently active layout when more than one layout is defined.

Answer (score 19):

Use this to get the code for the current layout:

```sh
$(xset -q|grep LED| awk '{ print $10 }')
```

This might needs to be converted to a form you want, like:

```sh
case "$(xset -q|grep LED| awk '{ print $10 }')" in
  "00000002") KBD="English" ;;
  "00001002") KBD="Thai" ;;
  *) KBD="unknown" ;;
esac
```

Comment: I get `00000002` even though my layout is "USA Dvorak international". Language is not enough...

Comment: It doesn't help if there are three or more layouts. The second and the third layouts give the same value `00001004` on my machine.

Comment: problem: toggle your numlock and start this command again ;)

Comment: This will not work reliably - you need to use a mask since the LED indicates the status of the keyboard led buttons as well.

Answer (score 17):

The answers so far did not work for me. I use `setkbmap` with two layouts english and czech so any `-print` or `-query` will always return the two. Grepping the LED status for `xset -q` does not work either since that one shows the status of all keyboard leds.

The best so far was to quickly write this small utility:
https://gist.github.com/fikovnik/ef428e82a26774280c4fdf8f96ce8eeb

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <X11/XKBlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XKBrules.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

  if (dpy == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  XkbStateRec state;
  XkbGetState(dpy, XkbUseCoreKbd, &state);

  XkbDescPtr desc = XkbGetKeyboard(dpy, XkbAllComponentsMask, XkbUseCoreKbd);
  char *group = XGetAtomName(dpy, desc->names->groups[state.group]);
  printf("Full name: %s\n", group);

  XkbRF_VarDefsRec vd;
  XkbRF_GetNamesProp(dpy, NULL, &vd);

  char *tok = strtok(vd.layout, ",");

  for (int i = 0; i < state.group; i++) {
    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    if (tok == NULL) {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  printf("Layout name: %s\n", tok);

  return 0;
}
```

and compile using

`gcc -I/usr/include getxkblayout.c -lX11 -lxkbfile`

Comment: In which package is `XKBrules.h` contained? `x11proto-dev` does not contain it.

Comment: @nephewtom  libxkbfile

Comment: Works like a charm (y)

Answer (score 13):

You can use **`xkbprint`** to print the current layout.

For example to print the current layout as PDF use

```bsh
xkbprint -color "${DISPLAY}" - |\
    ps2pdf - > current_keyboard_layout.pdf
```

which produces:

[image: xkbprint result]

Comment: This is one of the reasons I don't recommend using `xmodmap`, use `setxkbmap` and `xkbcomp` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Another simpler approach, because of fixed positions of the output of the `xset -q` command, is this:

```
xset -q | grep -A 0 'LED' | cut -c59-67
```

It prints `00000002` or `00001002` depending on your current keyboard layout.

Comment: I like this one, I think you can narrow it down to 8 chars.
`c59-66`.

Comment: It seems to need `-c76-84` as of today

Answer (score 7):

On newer systems, you can use

`localectl status`

It will for instance show you the following:

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
```

Comment: doesn't show the currently active layout when more than one layout is defined, only shows the first

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer: **On KDE**, you can apparently get the current keyboard layout through the `qdbus` command:

```
$ qdbus org.kde.keyboard /Layouts getCurrentLayout
gb(intl)
```

I have several layouts configured, but it only shows the one that is currently in use.

Tested on Kubuntu 18.04 (qdbus version 4.8.7). There may be other d-bus based solutions for non-Qt environments, but I do not know about them.

Comment: I'd wish there would be some generic solution which "just works"(tm) on any X11 desktop you can imagine, like KDE, GNOME and, say, WubbaLubbaDubDub.

Answer (score 3):

With GNOME D-Bus you can do it like this:

```
$ gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval  "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().currentSource.id"
(true, '"ru"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Below gives me the current keyboard layout,

`setxkbmap -query | awk '/layout/ {print $2}'`.

Following script toggles the keyboard layout. I personally prefer this to `grp:alt_shift_toggle` and similar options.

```bsh
LAYOUT=$(setxkbmap -query | awk '/layout/ {print $2}')

if [[ "$LAYOUT" == "ir" ]]; then
   setxkbmap us
else
   setxkbmap ir
fi
```

Comment: At my side **`setxkbmap -query | awk '/layout/ {print $2}'`** gives `us,de,us`.  It does not return the current keyboard layout but **gives the available keyboard layouts**.  And after `setxkbmap us` the `Win+SPC` no more toggles to German, so **this approach has bad sideffects**.

Comment: @Tino It print those languages because either you (with command `setxkbmap -layout us,de`) or the system at the startup set it like so. you can put the command `setxkbmap <default language>` in the startup scripts like `.xinitrc` or `.xprofile` to fix it. Afterwards when you query for current keyboard layout, it'll show you one layout. `Win+SPC` does not work because `SPC` in German is different character from that in Eng. So when you switch German the combination won't work.So in this way, the best solution is to use a hotkey with non-printable characters like `Alt-Esc` or `Alt-shift` etc.

Answer (score 1):

When using [Sway](https://swaywm.org/), the output of `setxkbmap` was always `us`, although I had a different layout active.

I solved this using

```
swaymsg -t get_inputs | jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard") | .xkb_active_layout_name'
```

which accurately produces either `English (US)` or `German` on my machine.

The name of your keyboard may differ; get its name using `swaymsg -t get_inputs`.

The command above uses [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) for parsing the JSON output of `swaymsg`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Goosfrabaa in the Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=699187#p699187):

```
setxkbmap -v | awk -F "+" '/symbols/ {print $2}'
```

This works correctly here, and prints `us(dvorak-intl)` (displayed as "USA Dvorak international" in the GNOME keyboard selection menu).

Comment: It prints only the first layout in the list, not the current one.

Comment: How can I detect my keymap, when I use language toggle by setxkbmap?

`$ setxkbmap -v` >> `Trying to build keymap using the following components: | keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty) | types:      complete | compat:     complete+ledscroll(group_lock) | symbols:    pc+us+hu:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+compose(rwin)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp) |
geometry:   pc(pc105)` in this case I got everytime "us"

Answer (score 0):

You can query the LED mask value from `xset -q` command and then apply `00001000` mask to see if the primary or the seconday layout is in use. Example:

```
t=$(xset -q | grep LED)
# this will remove all trash in $t before the LED mask:
mask="0b${t##*mask:  }"
not_en_mask="0b00001000"
# Now we just apply bitwise AND to $mask and see if it is equals zero or not
[[ $((mask & not_en_mask)) == 0 ]] && echo EN || echo RU
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols
```

Comment: it returns overall keyboard settings, not current layout (us _or_ ru)

Comment: Execute it well, as @jasonwryan states if you analyze carefully that line, into it resides your layout. In my case it is `latam`.

Comment: jasonwryan version just output a part of string after '+', `xkb_symbols` value doesn't depend on selected layout, I always get 'us'