# How to put some keyboard layout aside from layout switching ring?

Tags: gnome, xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

What I need is to

1. switch between Russian and English layout with my favorite shortcut (namely <kbd>Shift-CapsLock</kbd>)
2. switch to Belarusian layout with another shortcut (say, <kbd>Ctrl-RightShift</kbd>, but actual binding doesn't matter)
3. while Belarusian layout is active, switch back to Russian/English with <kbd>Shift-CapsLock</kbd>

Is it possible with xkb at all? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

#### Three useful commands:

**1**. Get the current keyboard layout, from this [topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12072/how-do-i-get-current-keyboard-layout) :

```
setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols | awk -F"+" '{print $2}'
```

Returns layout(variant) where variant is optional

**2**. Know if the current keyboard layout is layout(variant):

```
 setxkbmap -print | grep "layout(variant)"
```

Or without "(variant)".

Returns nothing is not.

**3**. Set the keyboard layout to a specified value:

```
setxkbmap layout variant
```

Where variant is optional.

(see `man setxkbmap` for more informations)

#### What you can do:

**1**. Create a simple executable (`chmod +x file`) script that changes the keyboard layout on the fly, depending on the current one. For instance, if we deal with the first point:

```
#!/bin/bash

if setxkbmap -print | grep "us"
then
  setxkbmap ru
else
  setxkbmap us
fi
```

**2**. With your keyboard shortcuts manager, assign the `Shift-CapsLock` keys to this script.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

What you exactly want is not possible as it would require statefull process (to know the state previous of switching to `by` layout).

However, along with the ISO_Prev_Group and ISO_Next_Group symbols allowing to decrement/increment in the layouts ring, there is also those two: ISO_First_Group and ISO_Last_Group.
With this ring: `us,by,ru` you can always access any of the three layouts in a single toggle.

For example, define <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to send ISO_Last_Group when in `us` layout, ISO_First_Group when in `ru` or `by`; 
define <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>RightShift</kbd> to send ISO_Next_Group when in `us` ISO_Prev_Group when in `ru` and ISO_Next_Group (or Last) when in `by`.

The difference with what you want is that you have to manually choose (with different shortcuts) the layout you want to go, when in `by`.

Also, if you need `by` layout for just a few belarussian specific cyrillic letters; another option would be to use a modified `ru` layout, with extra symbols in some keys, accessible with an AltGr or similar key, like in most latin keyboards.

As in the `by` file there are only 3 different keys from `ru` it seems that would be the right approach.
In such cas I would stack the layouts as: `us,ru,by`

Use ISO_Next_Group in "us", ISO_Prev_Group in "ru" for Shift-Capslock, and in "ru" define a key with a latching ISO_Next_Group.

To do that:
Create a ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd where you put the output of setxkbmap, it will be your base keyboard definition; eg:

```
setxkbmap "us,ru,by" ; setxkbmap -print > ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd
```

then create a file ~/.xkb/symbols/mysymbols with:

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "shift_caps_us_ru_by" {
  key <CAPS> {
    symbols[Group1] = [  Caps_Lock, ISO_Next_Group   ],
    symbols[Group2] = [  Caps_Lock, ISO_Prev_Group   ],
    symbols[Group3] = [  Caps_Lock, ISO_First_Group  ]
  };
  key <RALT> {
    symbols[Group2] = [ ISO_Group_Latch ]
  };
};
```

edit the `~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd` file, and change the `xkb_symbols` line to add `+mysymbols(shift_caps_us_ru_by)`

finally, you can load it with `xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd` and now <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> switch between latin (us) and cyrillic (ru) layouts; and while in cyrillic, you can access belarusian-specific letters holding <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (right Alt) key.

Answer (score 0):

All right, so what I was *really* wanted was switching layouts in MRU (most recently used) order. And guess what, GNOME's default layout switcher does *precisely* that (make sure no checkboxes in "Tweaks" → "Keyboard & Mouse" → "Additional Layout Options" → "Keys to change layout" are activated!). So currently I have 4 layouts in a ring (Russian, Belarusian, Ukrainian, English) and switching between most recent ones is one <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> away. So that solves the issue for me and then some.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [sxhkd](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) (simple X hotkey daemon).Its configuration should not be challenging at all. Follow the steps presented in the [archwiki tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sxhkd) and you'll get it up and running in no time.

For the sake of simplicity, sxhkd gives you the power to map/bind input events (like pressing a key down...) to actions (like changing the keyboard layout back and forth...)

I, personally, switch between 3 different layouts on the fly. The mappings I use :

```bsh
super + k; {u,f,r}
  setxkbmap {us,fr,ru}
```

<kbd>super</kbd> is a special key (called modifier), you can use other modifier keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> etc (it's all documented)

So when I hold press my modifier key (<kbd>super</kbd> the windows key in my case) and <kbd>k</kbd> then release both and press one of the three keys <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> it runs the command `setxkbmap` with one of the three arguments supplied depending on the key pressed (order is respected). Let's say I hit <kbd>super</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>then<kbd>f</kbd> I get `setxkbmap fr` the french layout

ps: if you bind, by accident, a combination of keys that is already associated with an action, you might get indesirable/unexpected results (most likely the late bindings will shadow the early ones). But keep in mind that everyting has always a fix. So dont be afraid to experiment.

Comment: Nice, does it work in Wayland?