# Adding custom setxkbmap options

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

[Use setxkbmap to swap the Left Shift and Left Control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control) describes how to swap some modifier keys with xkbcomp. However, I'd like to just add a custom setxkbmap option instead of using xkbcomp with a full layout definition. Similar to `setxkbmap -option local:swap_lwin_lctrl`, I'd like to swap right win & right control without modifying existing files in /usr/share/X11/xkb (which would be overwritten on package upgrade).

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue. From the doc, one could guess that the correct syntax would be something like that :

```
$ setxkbmap -I$HOME/.config/xkb -option mine:accent
```

Note : `~` doesn't work with the `-I` option

with

~/.config/xkb/symbols/azerty_altgr

```
partial default
xkb_symbols "accent" {
    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
    key <AE02>  { [  NoSymbol, NoSymbol, eacute,      NoSymbol ] };
    key <AE07>  { [  NoSymbol, NoSymbol, egrave,      NoSymbol ] };
    key <AE09>  { [  NoSymbol, NoSymbol, asciicircum, NoSymbol ] };
    key <AE10>  { [  NoSymbol, NoSymbol, agrave,      NoSymbol ] };
};
```

or whatever symbole file you have and

~/.config/xkb/rules/evdev

```
! option        =   symbols
  mine:accent   =   +azerty_altgr(accent)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

---

The only solution I found is the following :
Use the same files described above. Set all native option using `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape,whatever`. Then :

```
$ setxkbmap -print > tempfile.txt
```

and edit `tempfile.txt` in order to add your custom option in the `xkb_symbols` line :

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+fr:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(swapescape)+azerty_altgr(accent)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

and finaly :

```
xkbcomp -I$HOME/.config/xkb tempfile.txt $DISPLAY
```

It can be generalised for any number of options.
This solution is deprecated according to [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension#Using_keymap_.28deprecated.29).

Comment: Great, thanks for this! I can confirm that it is still working as of 2018-01-25, and the archwiki warning has been updated to indicate that it might not be deprecated.