# replace menu key with capslock and capslock with left control using xkb

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, key-mapping, xkb

I followed the instruction here by defining my own xkbsymbols  ([Use setxkbmap to swap the Left Shift and Left Control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control/65600#65600))

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "replace_Menu_Capslock" {
    replace key <COMP>  { [ Caps_Lock ] };
    replace key <CAPS>  { [ Control_L ] };
};
```

The menu key now becomes Caps_Lock, but I can't get the Caps_Lock as Left Control work. Please help.

Comment: After trial and error, I finally done with this:partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "replace_Menu_Capslock" {
  replace key <CAPS>  {  [ Control_R ]};
  replace key <RCTL>  {  [ Caps_Lock ] };
  replace key <MENU> { [ Control_R, Control_R ] };
  modifier_map Control { Control_L, <MENU> };
}; Still it would be good to know why?