# Keyboard remap: home → comma, end → dot

Tags: keyboard, xkb

I'm trying to change `xkb` settings in this file: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`.  Specifically, I tried this:

```
    // <AB08> = 59;
    // <AB09> = 60;
    // <HOME> = 110;
    // <END> = 115;

    <HOME> = 59;
    <END> = 60;

    <AB08> = 59;
    <AB09> = 60;
```

(I tried all three combinations, i.e. map all of them to 110/115 or map home=59, end=60, comma=110, end=115).  In neither case I can get both <kbd>.</kbd> to print dot and <kbd>End</kbd> to print dot.

The commented combination is the original values.

I'll admit, I don't understand how this mapping works.  I thought I did, but now it doesn't make any sense any more.

---

In case, what I'm asking for wasn't clear: I don't need <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> (I'm using Emacs, and the functionality of these keys is implemented differently), but on my keyboard these keys are in the premium space, so I would really like to use them for something I use a lot: comma and dot (which on my keyboard are difficult to press).

Comment: Did you edit a file in `/usr/lib/X11/xkb`? Then you may try to edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` also. `key <HOME> {[ comma, less, horizconnector, multiply]};`

Comment: @Andra hm, I'll try. I'd still like to know why the straight-forward approach didn't work.

Comment: As fas as I understand, you shouldn't edit those files but, instead, load your `hidden partial alphanumeric_keys xkb_symbols` remapping. I can't help further.

Comment: For myself, I would do it using `xmodmap`.

Comment: @Andra a bit of caution about xmodmap: it's terribly slow on Arch. I.e. I need to hold the remapped keys for ~5 seconds until it takes effect. Have no idea why.

Comment: OK, I did remapping according to [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control), and it did indeed work (home → comma, end → dot). To get key codes and definitions I needed `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/lv` (lv is my layout).

Comment: @Andra that's the thing: swapping works, but I need duplication, not swapping.

Comment: no, why _swapping_? You can write your own remapping.