# Reassigning Right_Control from control modifier key to mod3 without using xmodmap

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, xmodmap, setxkbmap

I am doing a task that is taking me longer than expected as `xmodmap` cannot be combined with other commands such as `setxkbmap` and so on.
My goal is to change `Right_Control` key from been assigned on `control` to `mod3` as per `xmodmap` terminology

Thanks to this post I was able to assign it to that key : [Use setxkbmap to swap the Left Shift and Left Control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control/65600#65600)

The problem is that now I still have assigned Right_Control to "control" , and I need to remove this assignment

To sum up the steps I have followed:

(note that I have previously used fa as my custom layout I already have files in /usr/shareX11/xkb/symbols/fa and etc...)

```
mkdir -p ~/.xkb/symbols/keymap
mkdir -p ~/.xkb/symbols/
sudo vi ~/.xkb/symbols/assigningmod3
```

Included

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "assign_rctl_to_mod3" {
    modifier_map Mod3 { <RCTL> };
};
```

Then

```
setxkbmap -print > ~/.xkb/keymap/fa
sudo vi ~/.xkb/keymap/fa
```

And added the underlined part to it

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+fa+inet(evdev)+assigningmod3(assign_rctl_to_mod3)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };     ----------------------------------
};
```

Then include this line in my .xinitrc

```
xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/fa $DISPLAY 2> /dev/null
```

Restarting now my X11Server
The issue now Is that when I check for the assignments `xmodmap` I have

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
                               ----------------
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        Control_R (0x69)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

As you can see I have underlined the assignment I need to still remove , in the other hand `mod3` has been assigned correctly.
If I trace where I may have to modify it be to the original assignment of the key at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/level3` line no92

```
xkb_symbols "switch" {
  key <RCTL> {
    type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1] = [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
  };
  include "level3(modifier_mapping)"
};
```

But I don't really feel confindent on tweaking anything on there. You know how to assign this?

Answer (score 0):

Although you may experience some issue when invoking `xmodmap` to load whole templates files. It is perfectly fine to delete this key-assignment by using `xmodmap` on `.xinitrc` by just adding below `xkbcomp` invokation the following line

```
/usr/bin/xmodmap -e 'remove control = Control_R'
```